# Computing norms in quotient space $l_\infty/c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $F \subset E$ a closed subspace.

We define $[x]=\{x+u: u \in F\}$ and $E/F = \{[x]: x \in E\}$

The norm on $E/F$ is given by: $$ \|[x]\| =\inf\limits_{u \in F} ||x+u||.$$

Now, let $E = l_\infty$ and $F = c_0$. I need to compute $\|[x]\|$ for $x = (1,1,1, \cdots )$ .

**My attempt:**

Let $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\in c_0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $\xi_i \rightarrow 0$, there exists $n_0$ such that $|\xi_i|<\frac{1}{n}$
,$ \forall i \geq n_0.$

We have:

$$||(1+\xi_1, 1+\xi_2, \cdots)||_\infty =\sup\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}}
|1+ \xi_i| \geq |1+ \xi_{n_0}|  \geq |1- |\xi_{n_0}|| = 1- |\xi_{n_0}| \geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$$

Since $n$ and $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\in c_0$ were arbitrary:
$$||(1+\xi_1, 1+\xi_2, \cdots)||_\infty \geq 1, \forall (\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\in c_0$$

Thus:
$$\|[x]\|= 
\inf\limits_{(\xi_i) \in c_0} ||(1,1,\cdots) + (\xi_1, \xi_2, \cdots)||_\infty =
\inf\limits_{(\xi_i) \in c_0} ||(1+\xi_1, 1+\xi_2, \cdots)||_\infty \geq 1$$

If $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} = 0 \in c_0$, we have $||(1+\xi_1, 1+\xi_2, \cdots)||_\infty =1$. Hence $\|[x]\| = 1$.

Am I right?

Comment: While $\ell_p$ spaces are well-known, wouldn't it be useful to specify that $c_0$ is  the space of all sequences converging to zero?

Comment: @LaurentDuval, I don't think as as this symbol is completely standard.

Comment: Yes. This proof is fine, although I am not fond of the notation $(\xi_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}=0 \in c_0$. I would prefer if $\xi_i =0$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$, then $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in c_0$.

Comment: @Tomek Kania OK my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct. It can be stated a bit more neatly:

The zero sequence is in $c_0$, so we always have

$$\|[x]\|=\inf_{u\in c_0}\|x+u\|\le \|x\|\;;$$

for $x=\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ that means that $\|[x]\|\le 1$. To show that $\|[x]\|\ge 1$ and hence that $\|[x]\|=1$, suppose that $\epsilon>0$; we want to show that $\|[x]\|>1-\epsilon$, i.e., that $\|x+u\|>1-\epsilon$ for each $u\in c_0$. Taking $u=\langle\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\ldots\rangle$, we want to show that

$$\sup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}|1+\xi_n|>1-\epsilon\;.$$

Since $u\in c_0$, there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|\xi_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$. In particular,

$$\sup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}|1+\xi_n|\ge|1+\xi_{m_\epsilon}|\ge 1-|\xi_{m_\epsilon}|>1-\epsilon\;,$$

as desired.