# Infinity norm quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ the canonical $n$ dimensional real vector space.
We endow $V$ with the infinity norm defined as $\|x\|_\infty = \max_i |x_i|$ for any vector $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in V$.

Let then $V'$ be a strict subspace of $V$. One can consider the quotient 
$$V/V'$$ which is naturally normed by the quotient norm:
$$ \| x + V' \|_\infty = \inf_{v\in V'} \|x-v\|_\infty.$$

Is there a convenient way to compute generically this norm or at least get (non-trivial) bounds on it ?

In the $\ell_2$ norm case, this reduces easily to the computation of the
orthogonal projection of $x$ on the space $V'$, which can be performed by
Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation.

Comment: This is just using Gram-Schmidt with a different norm in the computations.

Comment: @Math1000 How do you define the orthogonal projection operator for Gram-Schmidt when the norm isn't induced by an inner product?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Ah, good point. Indeed the parallelogram identity does not hold for this norm, so there is no inner product to work with :)

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713005/computing-norms-in-quotient-space-l-infty-c-0/1713092

Comment: @Math1000: that's not directly related to this setting in the linked question, OP is dealing with a very specific subspace of $\ell_\infty$. I'm working in finite dimension and my subspace can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

The unit ball in infinity-norm is a [*zonotope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron), the Minkowski sum of several line segments. The zonotope structure is preserved under linear map, in particular under the quotient map. Thus, the unit ball of the quotient space is also a zonotope.

The converse is also true: every zonotope is a projection of a cube, so every normed space whose unit ball is a zonotope is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient of $(\mathbb{R}^n, \ell_\infty)$ for sufficiently large $n$.

In practical terms, this allows for an explicit description of the unit ball of $V/V'$. Pick some subspace $W\subset V$ that is a complement of $V'$; the Euclidean-orthogonal complement is a natural choice. For each $k=1,\dots, n$, let $p_k$ be the projection of the $k$th standard basis vector of $V$ onto $W$ along $V'$ (so, if $W\perp V'$, this is orthogonal projection). Then the unit ball of $V/V'$, as represented by $W$, is the Minkowski sum of line segments $[-p_k, p_k]$, that is 
$$
B = \left\{\sum_{k=1}^n c_k p_k : -1\le c_k\le 1\right\}
$$
For a concrete $V'$, one may be able to grasp the geometry of $B$, and then the description of the norm follows.

Formally, for $x\in W$ the quotient norm is
$$
\|x\| = \inf\left\{\max|c_k| : x = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k p_k\right\}
$$
where the infimum is taken over all such representations; however this isn't really different from the definition.

Comment: I agree, and this can give upper bounds by carefully choosing the hyperplanes. Are you aware of a bound that could be derived from the probabilistic method?

Comment: I don't know. Also, "a bound" is vague; it has to be in terms of something. Or are you looking for a bound independent of subspace $V'$?

Comment: You’re right. I was meaning a bound in terms of a norm of a given basis of the space V’ ( seen as a matrix).